# Python thread executing function twice

Tags: python, multithreading

Atm I'm working on a game using tkinter. I'm working on algorithm that moves enemies through the game map.

I will post only relevant lines, since the code is quiet hard-to-read.

I'm using class Timer imported from threading.
2 relevant functions are:

```
def add_enemies(self):
  enemy = self.enemies.pop(0)
  if enemy in '.':
     Timer(1, self.add_enemies).start()
  else:
     self.move_enemy(enemy,set())
     if not self.game_ended and self.enemies:
        Timer(1, self.add_enemies).start()

def move_enemy(self, enemy, visited):
  if type(enemy) == str:
     if enemy in 'm':
        enemy = Mongol(self.canvas, *self.start)
  visited.add((enemy.x,enemy.y))
  for move in (-1,0),(0,1),(1,0),(0,-1):
      pos = (enemy.x + move[0], enemy.y+move[1])
      if pos in self.way and pos not in visited:
          print(pos)
          enemy.move(*move)
          enemy.take_shot(6)
          visited.add(pos)
          Timer(0.5, lambda: self.move_enemy(enemy, visited)).start()
```

This function should move the enemy, wait 0.5 second, then create a thread in which it recursively calls itself and moves the enemy again.

It might not be the best solution the create another thread inside the thread, but all other solutions made my GUI to freeze while executing the function.

Problem is, that Timer executes function move_enemy twice. Nothing else in the code can cause this problem.

Simple print test of enemy position shows this:

[image]

It simply moves the enemy twice, and increases its position twice as shown on the picture.

Comment: You need to post way more lines, make an MCVE for us. http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: Add your code to the question

Comment: What are you really trying to do with your lines like `if x in 'y'`? Also, once you create a new `Timer` in `move_enemy`, why do you continue to look at other possible moves?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problem was, that tkinter is not thread safe hence it doesn't act deterministic.
I solved the problem by using Queue. My main thread, in which tkinter runs, periodically checks wheter or not it has something to draw.

Answer (score 0):

This is a wild guess, but substituting the `enemy` object with a new `enemy` object with a modified location in
`Timer(0.5, lambda: self.move_enemy(enemy, visited)).start()` might get the inbetween coordinates ((3,1),(5,1) and others). (If you do the same thing twice with the same input, you get two identical values.)

From the output I deduce: `visited.add(pos)` doesn't add positions to `visited` hence the `if pos in self.way and pos not in visited:` clause doesn't filter out already tested values (hence the (2,1)(2,1) printout). Try, if `.append()` works better.

I tried my best :D gl hf

Answer (score 0):

Judging from the output, it looks like what's actually happening is that you were expecting things to execute in this order

```
print
move
print
move
print
move
print
move
....
```

but you failed to include enough synchronization and they are instead happening in this order:

```
print
print
move
move
print
print
move
move
....
```

It's not doing anything *extra*: it's just doing things not in the order you were hoping for.